# Why is my cmd closes immediately? (when I open .bat it closes)

Tags: batch-file

This is the .bat code

```
git pull
@echo off

set PYTHON=
set GIT=
set VENV_DIR=
set COMMANDLINE_ARGS=

call webui.bat
```

Please help me answer this problem

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about python. How do you run this? Do you double-click an icon and the window disappears immediately? Then run from a command line. Is it webui.bat that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to debug (i.e. answer your question of "Why?")

##### 1. Try entering each line one-by-one.

Which line gives an error and what error message do you get?

##### 2. If you get no errors, try pausing at the end

You can do this by adding this to the end of the batch file:

```
timeout 60
```

That will give you 1 minute to review the results

### My guess with no other information?

Assuming the git pull was successful, the most likely culprit is `webui.bat`. Have you checked that the file is in the current folder? And that it doesn't itself trigger an error?

Answer (score 1):

After execution of the code terminal window is closed by default. Try setting a pause in your batch code, as follows:

```
<your code>
pause
```